# Tag Manager Query

Tags: containers, google-tag-manager

The related tag is executing a GTM container within itself, creating a potential security risk on the site. It would be ideal for us to gain access to that nested container to determine what is within it and migrate it to the parent container in order to remove the nested container completely.

What could be the possible solution of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well just look at the ID of the other container, reach out to whoever manages your GTM assets and task them with finding the owner of the mentioned container and gain access.

If you want to copy things over from that container to yours and get rid of it without having access to it... You could inspect your local sources, but that would just be a lot of minified code mixed with user logic. There used to be this tool called GTM spy, but it's not available currently. Finally, you can just block that container from loading and study what changes in the DOM and in the Network tab when you smoke test main functionalities of the site.